# Is there a library alternative to gcc stack-protector / fortify source feature on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, security, buffer-overflow, fortify-source

Is there an external library/approach/whatever to add

1. canary protection (stack-protector equivalent)
2. extra buffer boundary check (fortify source equivalent)

to C software without using glibc / gcc (stack-protector/fortify source) built-in functionality?

Comment: It is impossible implement such functionality without compiler help. Gcc, for example, inserts extra checks inside generated code. By the way, do you want a solution with explicit call to check functions?

Comment: Sorry, I try to explain myself better. What I mean is, I can't use fortify_source/stack-protector and I want similar result with different technology.

Comment: @boos: Why can't you use stack protector and fortify source?  Their great merit is that they operate on the code as it is compiled without changing it.  Any library-based solution will require you to change the source code, won't it?  Or what do you have in mind — what sort of magic are you seeking?

Comment: I can't link glibc, it's not a standalone software but it's more like a sort of firmware/kernel. That is why I can't use glibc. In term of black magic, maybe something that wrap error prone function and add some extra checks.

Comment: @boos you don't need to use glibc to use the stack protection features of gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack protector has nothing to do with glibc; you just have to provide the symbol `__stack_chk_fail` which will be called by the canary checking code generated by GCC. (If you're generating position-independent code, you also need `__stack_chk_fail_local` which has hidden visibility and thus can be called without the GOT pointer being initialized.) You also need to make sure the canary storage is available and initialized; depending on the architecture/ABI you're using, this may be in a global named `__stack_chk_guard` or at a particular fixed offset from the thread pointer (`%gs:0` on x86).

As for `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`, you can reproduce the equivalent with GCC builtins similar to how glibc's headers do it. This could be done as an independent layer separate from the libc headers, via GCC's `#include_next` feature and a secondary include directory wrapping the standard headers, with no dependency on the particular libc implementation in use. As far as I know, no such implementation presently exists, but we very much want one for use with musl libc. You could try reaching out to our development team/community and see if anyone's interested in helping you work on it or prioritizing development of such headers.

Comment: @R: I've finally recognized that, I've compiled the code with --stack-protector-all -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 and I'm trying to port both __stack_chk_fail, __stack_check_guard functions. Unfortunately I can't use a linker to initialize the value of the canary with random data. I will need to find a way to initialize that value at software startup.